# Execution sequence of MVC Routes and HTTP Modules

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, httpmodule

Does the handler for MVC Routes trump the HttpModules defined in `web.config`?

I have an asp.net app that consists of legacy webforms code and MVC code. I want to prove to myself that MVC is taking precedence for handling requests over a custom HttpModule the project uses, which can also handle requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>IIRC the MVC routing is done in the HTTP module which launches MVC. So MVC will "win" as long as it's http module is added before your custom one.</del>

I was almost correct. MVC implements a [UrlRoutingHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.urlroutinghandler.aspx) which means that it will direct the request before any module is invoked.

Source code:

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/5b4f63fa0b89#src%2fSystem.Web.Mvc%2fMvcHttpHandler.cs